# How to return to the place in my workbook where the button was clicked?

Tags: excel, vba

In my workbook I have many ToggleButton in different sheets that get me to the same sheet (SheetX) and then from that sheet I want to return where the ToggleButton was pressed.

Is there a better way to do this that infinite If/End If statement

Hope I'm clear enough

```
Private Sub CommandButton12_Click()

    If Sheets("T1").ToggleButton1.Value = True Or Sheets("T2").ToggleButton1.Value = True Then

        Sheets("T2").Select

            If Sheets("T1").ToggleButton1.Value = True Or Sheets("T2").ToggleButton1.Value = True Or Sheets("T3").ToggleButton1.Value = True Then

                Sheets("T3").Select

            End If

            'So on and on and on

    Else

        Sheets("T1").Select

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: See [Application.Caller](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother/using-applicationcaller-to-reference-the-worksheet/b861723e-c7aa-4944-b15a-5cda0d8d3da8?auth=1)

Answer (score 0):

From Scott's suggestion, you can use a global variable and have sheet 1 use a button to go back to the last saved items, such as:

```
Public r as Long, Public c as Long, Public s as Worksheet

Sub Global_Hold_Macro()
     'You would put "Globlal_Hold_Macro" in each togglebutton
     r = Activecell.Row
     c = Activecell.Column
     s = Activesheet.Name
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Sheet1_Toggle_To_Go_Back()
    s.cells(r,c).Select
End Sub
```

---

**Edit:**

Will show this to call a specific named shape, in this case a button:

```
Public r as String
Public c as String

Sub Global_Hold_Macro()
     'You would put "Globlal_Hold_Macro" in each togglebutton
     r = Application.Caller
     c = Activesheet.Name
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Sheet1_Toggle_To_Go_Back()
    Sheets(c).Activate
    Sheets(c).Shapes(r).Select
End Sub
```

This may not work if you use certain types of buttons/shapes.

Comment: The Sheet1_Toggle_To_GO_Back Sub doesn't work I have the message Object needed

Comment: @MaxBridge Did you change your references in the Global_Hold_Macro to be appropriate to your toggle?  I used r, c, and s, as examples showing the complexity of what needs to be captured.  If your button isn't tied to a cell, then the r & c will not be recorded appropriately, though the s is activesheet, so it is captured.

Comment: Object is required when I press the go back button. I would guess a problem with the declaration of my public variable

Comment: @MaxBridge Sorry, I forgot to put in the sheet activate before selecting the button shape.  It causes that issue.  Updated my post.

Comment: Where do I put the public variable beacause c in the Sub Sheet1_Toggle_To_Go_Back() is empty?

Comment: @MaxBridge It should be at the top of a module, outside of all subs.  It might be best to make a module just for the global variables.